# Call a method of T only if T has the method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

I'm trying to do a sort of a compile time duck-typing. I want to call the method if T has it, otherwise do nothing. This could be implemented as template function that does nothing, with a specialization that calls the method. But how to select the specialization only if T has a foo()?

Comment: Did not understand it well, but why not use `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: decltype and SFINAE, friend.